# Processing 3: Transparent textures blocking others

Tags: java, 3d, textures, processing, transparent

What I try to do is fading (in and out) textures on a custom shape (with beginShape(QUADS)) in Processing 3.3.6.

The problem is, that the blocks (see following picture) cover others in a weird way:

[image: Transparent texture blocking vision]

What's even weirder is that the ground doesn't get blocked out.

In the code I'm basically drawing the ground, then I draw the blocks with beginshape and a texture.

For the transparency I call "tint(255, alphavalue)" and "noTint()".

What I'm trying to achieve is a fadeIn and fadeOut of transparency on the ground and blocks as an alternative to the more resource expensive fog (which I didn't seem to find an easy way for).

Does anyone know an easier way than tinting texture with alpha to achieve a truly transparent texture in processing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. In the future, please try to post a [mcve] along with your question.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you for improving my skill. I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

The problem is **depth sorting.**

Basically, processing is sorting by draw order by default, but it should be sorted by depth.

To fix this, I call:

```
hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
```

before drawing the blocks and to save processing power, I call

```
hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
```

after.